# Why doesn't Typescript check assignment for this deeply nested type definition?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've created a type structure for a specific use case that involves recursively nested typing:

```
type ErrorNodeDetails = {example: number}

type ErrorNode<FormData> = FormData extends Array<infer ArrayItem>
  ? ErrorNode<ArrayItem>
  : FormData extends Primitive
  ? ErrorNodeDetails
  : ErrorNodeDetails & {
      children?: Readonly<{
        [K in keyof FormData]?: ErrorNode<FormData[K]>
      }>
    }

export type ErrorMap<FormData extends Record<string, unknown>> = {
  [K in keyof FormData]?: ErrorNode<FormData[K]>
}
```

The resulting structure seems to be correctly like I expect, I can verify that by defining an object as of the `ErrorMap` type, TS in that case only allows me to access the expected keys, even deeply nested, but for the assignment, TS doesn't perform the checks adequately for the deeper levels (over 4 levels):

```
const x: ErrorMap<{ x: { d: { c: 1 } } }> = {
      x: {
        example: 1,
        children: {
          d: {
            children: { // Up to this level, TS enforces the correct types. I can't change `children` to `c`.
              c1: { s: 1 }, // c1 shouldn't be allowed, but it is, as is anything within it.
            },
            example: 1,
          },
        },
      },
    }

    x.x?.children?.d?.children?.c // When accessing the values, even deep, TS gives the autocomplete as expected, and doesn't allow to access inexistent keys.
```

Is this some limitation of Typescript, or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for; is [this](https://tsplay.dev/wRXznm) what you want to achieve?

Comment: @caTS Hmm, yeah, actually that does seem to do the trick. After I asked the question I thought this could be the problem: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47935

It still does seem like it might be related, but maybe your solution is a workaround to this issue?

Would you mind writing an answer, and explaining a bit more why this works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TS is putting off computing the mapped type in here:

```
type ErrorNode<FormData> = FormData extends Array<infer ArrayItem>
  ? ErrorNode<ArrayItem>
  : FormData extends Primitive
  ? ErrorNodeDetails
  : ErrorNodeDetails & {
      children?: Readonly<{
        [K in keyof FormData]?: ErrorNode<FormData[K]>
      }>
    }
```

but we can force it to compute what it is in full with this little trick:

```
type ErrorNode<FormData> = FormData extends Array<infer ArrayItem>
    ? ErrorNode<ArrayItem>
    : FormData extends Primitive
    ? ErrorNodeDetails
    : (ErrorNodeDetails & {
          children?: Readonly<
              {
                  [K in keyof FormData]?: ErrorNode<FormData[K]>;
              }
          >;
      }) extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never; // magic
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wRXznm)